# Python extract data from file and output to another

Tags: list, python-2.7, url

I have a text file with a list of urls. Given a url like each is a line by itself: "[https://www.amazon.com/George-Foreman-GRP1060B-Serving-Removable/dp/B00KDVJLJW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KDVJLJW)"
"[https://www.amazon.com/ThermoPro-Wireless-Digital-Kitchen-Thermometer/dp/B014DAVCP4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014DAVCP4)"

Here is the code:

```
linedata = []

with open("url.list") as f:
    for line in f:
        linedata = line.split('/')

        Title = '/'.join(linedata[3:4])
        Asin = ''.join(linedata[5]) + ''

f = open("url.text","a")

    for list in linedata:
    f.write(str(Asin))
    f.write('\n')

f.close
```

The code works partially. The loop doesn't work why ? and how do I write Title and asin to file on the same line? I am running python 2.7 and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming url.list has 1 url per line)This is what you should do :

```
linedata = []
reqData = []

with open("url.list") as f:
    for line in f:
        linedata = line.split('/')
        reqData.append(linedata[3]+' : '+linedata[5].split('"')[0])



f = open("url.text","a")

for data in reqData:
    f.write(str(data))
    f.write('\n')

f.close()
```

Comment: Fixed the indented, but it still just write the last value to the url.text file.  So I guess its not loop problem, but with the list and string.

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly, is there document to read or an explanation on why you need have another list(reqData)?

Comment: I'm using reqData to store the title and the asin in a list so that I can access it while writing it in the new file , in your code you're overwriting and not appending that is why you're code didn't work.

Comment: Thanks I understand now